# Infinitely Many Terms in Two Sequences Which Differ by Two

Tags: number-theory, geometric-progressions

Can it be shown that for any two arbitrary sequences of the form $2^kn$ and $2^km$ where $k,m,n \in \mathbb Z$, with $k > 0$, $m$ and $n$ are both odd, that there are infinitely many numbers in those sequences which differ by 2?

Edit: I am asking whether there are infinitely many terms in those sequences that differ by 2. For instance, if we look infinitely far in those sequences, would we find infinitely many occurrences where $2^km = 2^jn +2$ or $2^km +2 = 2^jn$?

Comment: Yes. For two fixed odd numbers $m$ and $n$, can it be shown that there are infinitely many terms in their sequences that differ by two?

Comment: It isn't clear what "two arbitrary sequences" you have in mind.  You might be thinking that some of the parameters $k,m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ vary and some are fixed, but it is unclear how one might define the two sequences by some such scheme.

Comment: If $m,n$ are fixed odd numbers and $k$ is allowed to take values $1,2,3,...$, then no, there cannot be infinitely many pairs in those sequences which differ by $2$.

Comment: @nicole This is never true regardless of the value of $m$ and $n$.  It seems like you didn't look very far for examples :).

Comment: @ErickWong I meant arbitrary terms in those sequences.

Comment: @nicole As did I.  Show us some examples if you disagree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $m,n$ be fixed (positive) odd integers, and consider the sequences $\{2^k m\}_{k\ge 1}$ and $\{2^j n\}_{j\ge 1}$.

If $2^{k} m$ and $2^{j} n$ differ by two, then $2^{k-1} m$ and $2^{j-1} n$ will differ by one.  Thus one of these is odd and the other is even.  Only if $k = 1$ or $j = 1$ is the corresponding term odd, so this cannot happen infinitely many times.

It can happen at most twice, e.g. when $m=1$ and $n=3$ we get two pairs that differ by two:

$$ (4,6) \text{ and } (8,6) $$

The fact that all (even) positive integers appear exactly once in *some* sequence of the kind originally specified by the OP is occasionally useful.  See this [recent Problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/103892/the-strange-ordering-of-sharkovskii) in Code Golf SE, "The strange ordering of Sharkovskii".

Comment: Sorry, I meant arbitrary terms in those sequences. So for instance, we have with $m=1$, the sequence $1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ...$ and for $n=3$, we have $3, 6, 12, 24, ...$. Would there be infinitely many terms that differ by 2, where the $k$ for each does not have to be the same?

Comment: Look, nicole, at what hardmath has written. There's a $k_1$ and a $k_2$, and no requirement that they be equal. Your question is answered.

Comment: Those subscripts on superscripts are pretty tiny and hard to spot.  I'll edit to use $k$ and $j$ as exponents, like the OP's recent edit to the Question.